# Will company deny boarding because of covid-related travel restrictions?

Tags: usa, borders, eu, covid-19

I am planning on traveling to the EU in the coming days, leaving from the US. I am the spouse of an EU citizen.

My spouse and I will be traveling together and based on this, https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/health/coronavirus-response/travel-and-transportation-during-coronavirus-pandemic/travel-and-eu-during-pandemic_en should be exempt from travel restrictions.

However, we recognize the current uncertainty and asked for formal confirmation from my spouse's home country that I will not be turned down at the border, which we have obtained.

Now, our main concern is that the airline might turn me down at boarding.

Are US airlines currently enforcing covid-related travel restrictions at boarding themselves? By that I mean, do US airlines currently use their own best interpretation of the travel restrictions in the destination country to decide whether to let someone board or not? Or do airlines leave that the destination country, only checking "pre-covid" travel requirements (e.g., non-expired passport, and no plan on staying more than 90 days)?

Some more info:

- In case that helps to answer, we're traveling with Delta, heading to Belgium.
- I have tried to clarify this with Delta directly, but it's hard to get in touch with them at the moment and get a formal written confirmation that I won't be denied boarding because of covid-related travel restrictions.

Comment: Which country are you flying to? In theory EU law still applies to all of them but in practice it might make a difference. For what it's worth and as an example, French government websites do indicate that [transportation companies are supposed to check the temporary “certificate”](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage) so this goes beyond pre-covid requirements (but it's not clear they have to check what you wrote on the form in any way, just that you have it).

Comment: Have you checked what Timatic states? That's the reference most if not all airlines use, and the entry for France for instance is very long and detailed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I now indicate in the question, I am traveling to Belgium. Could you tell me more about how to access the Timatic information? I looked it up and ended up there: https://www.timaticweb.com/ but I don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: @FZS You have to use one of several airline interfaces, such as http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.